# Vectorized way to split a dataset into geometrically decreasing subsets

Tags: r

For my experiment I need to calculate the hurst exponent. Part of this requires me to split the data by repeatedly halving the total sample set until the number of elements in the subsets is below some threshold - usually 8 or 10.

So for example:

```
1: 1 Set of N
2: 2 Sets of N/2
3: 4 Sets of N/4 
...
```

This process would stop after `N/x` creates a subset of length smaller than the threshold.

There is an obvious way to do this, via a while loop. However, this is ugly and unoptimized.

Is there any function or functions available that will split a vector of data into a set of subsets in this way? Or am I stuck doing it the ugly unoptimized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to compute the row indices of the data to be split, then use those indices in a `lapply()` to compute the hurst exponent.

```
N <- 100  # N must be nrow(data), value 100 indicates total rows in data
split_indices <- lapply( 1:8, function(x) { 
  unlist( ifelse(test = (x == 1), 
                 yes  = N, 
                 no   = list( c( 1, 
                                 cumsum( floor( rep( x = N/x, times = x-1) ) ),
                                 N ) ) ) ) 
  } )

split_indices
# [[1]]
# [1] 100
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]   1  50 100
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]   1  33  66 100
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]   1  25  50  75 100
# 
# [[5]]
# [1]   1  20  40  60  80 100
# 
# [[6]]
# [1]   1  16  32  48  64  80 100
# 
# [[7]]
# [1]   1  14  28  42  56  70  84 100
# 
# [[8]]
# [1]   1  12  24  36  48  60  72  84 100
```

Now use the function for hurst exponent inside the `lapply()` loop.

```
lapply( split_indices, function( x ) --compute-hurst-exponent-- )
```